Forex API endpoint with price changes for fiat currencies
I would like to know if there is an API that shows price changes in 1h, 1day and 1week frames like cmc widget for example.
CMC Widget:
{"status":{"timestamp":"2024-09-11T03:32:01.896Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":2},"data":{"1":{"id":1,"name":"Bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","slug":"bitcoin","num_market_pairs":11672,"date_added":"2010-07-13T00:00:00.000Z","tags":["mineable","pow","sha-256","store-of-value","state-channel","coinbase-ventures-portfolio","three-arrows-capital-portfolio","polychain-capital-portfolio","binance-labs-portfolio","blockchain-capital-portfolio","boostvc-portfolio","cms-holdings-portfolio","dcg-portfolio","dragonfly-capital-portfolio","electric-capital-portfolio","fabric-ventures-portfolio","framework-ventures-portfolio","galaxy-digital-portfolio","huobi-capital-portfolio","alameda-research-portfolio","a16z-portfolio","1confirmation-portfolio","winklevoss-capital-portfolio","usv-portfolio","placeholder-ventures-portfolio","pantera-capital-portfolio","multicoin-capital-portfolio","paradigm-portfolio","bitcoin-ecosystem","ftx-bankruptcy-estate"],"max_supply":21000000,"circulating_supply":19752587,"total_supply":19752587,"is_active":1,"cmc_rank":1,"is_fiat":0,"last_updated":"2024-09-11T03:31:00.000Z","quote":{"":{"price":56713.614572161736,"volume_24h":29871234515.186623,"percent_change_1h":-0.4836312,"percent_change_24h":0.06304837,"percent_change_7d":-0.14585005,"market_cap":1120240605921.0925,"last_updated":"2024-09-11T03:28:56.000Z"},"USD":{"price":56713.614572161736,"volume_24h":29871234515.186623,"percent_change_1h":-0.4836312,"percent_change_24h":0.06304837,"percent_change_7d":-0.14585005,"market_cap":1120240605921.0925,"last_updated":"2024-09-11T03:31:00.000Z"}}}}}
Does something like this exist for Forex Pairs? For example Eur/USD? My main interest is about "percent_change_1h":-0.4836312,"percent_change_24h":0.06304837,"percent_change_7d":-0.14585005
